# Making a tab key on the right side of a full sized mac keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use mac OSX with a full sized keyboard (F1-F19, number pad arrow keys and FN, Home, End, Page UP/Down delete mini pad above the arrow keys).  My mouse is on the left side of the keyboard.  This allows use of the return key, the arrow keys and the number pad etc. with my right hand.  I would like to assign a key or key combination on the right side of the keyboard to operate the same as the tab key.  I am thinking a Function key or the Home key, or FN+??  I have QuickKeys and could use that if someone knows how.

If there is no way to make a key the equivalent of the tab key, then at the least I would like to make some equivalent to Cmd+Tab that I can use with my right hand.

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the answer on this is a program called [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) from ManyTricks.com.  That program gives me a much superior app switcher to the native mac app switcher *and* lets me assign the trigger key.  Just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to assign another key to tab with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele), but it didn't work with command-tab.

[image]

You could use QuicKeys to assign a shortcut for a macro that emulates pressing tab or command-tab, but there's probably no way to have it work with different modifier key combinations or when holding the key.

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) is probably the only way to change it consistently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer.  It has taken me to some places I needed to know about, though they were not the answer to this question for me.